# Is there any way open controller in older navigation

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, bottom-up

I am using bottom popup library and showing popup upto 1/3 height of the view and i want to push new screen from that controller.
Problem:-
When i try to open controller it also shows upto 1/3 of height because i declared height of navigation for popup.

I want to open controller to full screen

Please review bottom popup library for further visualization

Comment: why would you want to show it from the popup? that's how you do this and no UI that I know of does that. when someoen clicks a button in the popup, it should dismiss the pop up and then immediately present the viewcontroller you wanted to show from the button click

Comment: Hi Loxx,I already tried to perform action on completion of dismiss. But it didn't work for me as it is taking new navigation at that time                      dismiss(animated: true) {
            CommonFunctions.sharedInstance.PushToContrller(from: self, ToController: .AddCareReciever, Data: nil)
        }